# How to synchronise ui and data (dictionary)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a dictionary that contains data that I used to fill a Table in PyQt5.
The table looks roughly like this:

```
| Material | Amount |
+----------+--------+
| Iron     | 20     |
| ...      | ...    |
```

Now my question is, how changes that are made via the UI inside the table can be synchronised with the dictionary. E. g.: via the UI I change the amount value for iron to 30. This should also update the dictionary.

Edit: For example trigger a on change event or somthing like that, that would read the table and create a new dictionary, replacing the old one. (which seems to be laborious)

I createt the table with the following code:

```
   self.allMaterials = json.load(open('materials.json'))  # reads json file that contains all materials and there amounts

    for rowIndex, rawMaterial in enumerate(self.allMaterials["materials"]["raw"]):
        itemName = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(rawMaterial["name"])  # fills cell with material name
        itemName.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)  # makes cell read only
        itemAmount = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()  # creates widget for cell
        itemAmount.setData(QtCore.Qt.EditRole, rawMaterial["amount"])  # fills material amount and makes it editable

        self.tableMatRaw.setItem(rowIndex, 0, itemName)  # positioning cell
        self.tableMatRaw.setItem(rowIndex, 1, itemAmount)  # positioning cell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `pyqtSignal` defined as `value_changed = pyqtSignal(int)` in an initialization.

The UI should call a function when the value is changed, say

```
def change_UI_value(new_value, ...):
    # Update UI dictionary...
    # When a signal is emitted, you pass a int value
    value_changed.emit(sig_value)
```

Then you should have a function which would be triggered by the signal

```
def update_dict(sig_value):
    # Get Material and value to update
    dict[material] = value
```

Finally, add a connection between the signal and the function it triggers `value_changed[int].connect(update_dict)`.

When updating the data dictionary, you can pass the row through the signal or try to pass a tuple through the signal (never tried but worth a shot).

Anyway, pyqtSignal really helps with code architecture.